# Need to add button for remove single item at once

Tags: magento-2.1, cart

I need to add button/link into the basket page which will be able to remove a single item. Each item should have separate button for remove that item.

How can I insert it into `Magento_Checkout:cart/item/default.phtml` file?

Comment: jquery ?  you can add with jquery, create functions of jquery to hide a item, Access it in jquery using ID of item. and apply function of jquery like   ('#item1').hide();

Answer (score 1):

You can look how it's done in the base layout:
[image: magento 2 cart]

checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml adds template with remove link to item renderer:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
```

And remove.phtml template itself:

```
<a href="#"
title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove item')); ?>"
class="action action-delete"
data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDeletePostJson(); ?>'>
    <span>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Remove item')?>
    </span>
</a>
```

UPD:
You can use direct helper call in the `Magento_Checkout:cart/item/default.phtml` but this is **very, very bad** practice and I hope you won't use on the site

```
    <a href="#"
         title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove item')); ?>"
         class="action action-delete"
         data-post='<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getDeletePostJson($_item) ?>'>
         <span><?php echo __('Remove item')?></span>
    </a>
```

Comment: can I just use something like button inside default.phtml without using xml part?

Comment: Magento remove item from cart via AJAX request, but removing item from quote is not the only triggered process. It also updates browser local storage and regenerates the minicart content and counter.

Comment: Technically you can use url https://example.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/{quote_item_is}/form_key/{form_key}, but it will redirect you to the homepage, won't update minicart, expose form key in GET params.  I think you can't do it without writing additional code

Comment: can you help me? I need to have 2 buttons to each item in basket to update its quantity and remove the particular item.

I've used this line, but it doesnt display anything 
<?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo $block->getActions($_item); ?>

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Hi,
why is that very, very bad practice to use it like that?

problem is, Im not get anything for this code,
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getActions($_item) ?>

it should display default remove option using this, but in my theme, it didnt render anything

Comment: it adds an undeclared dependency to the code, helper should be injected into the block. Templates should operate only block methods. I've tested code on blank and luma themes and it displays the remove button, can't say what was chamnged in your theme and what should be added to make it work

Comment: Thanks for the help. sorry to bother, do you have any idea about that quantity update button? there is an input box with selected quantity and right next to it the Update button. when user change value on inout box and click on update, it should change the selected quantity right at the basket page without going back to detail page or anywhere. problem is, in blank, that update button applies to every item. if user mistakenly updated value in other product item, every item quantity is updated. I need single button only change its own value